# How to replace "leading zero" witin a string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

How can i replace or remove "0" from a string in bash
The string is based in [prefix][ID][suffix]
e.g. ZZZ00004500AA010 or ZZZ004500AA010
the result must be
ZZZ4500AA010
so i want to remove the leading 0's in the ID
At the moment i have this:

```
echo "ZZZ00004500AA010" | sed 's/0//'
echo "ZZZ004500AA010" | sed 's/0//'
```

which gives me : ZZZ0004500AA010 or ZZZ04500AA010

Comment: `sed 's/0\+//' file`

Comment: `sed -E 's/0+//'`? Or `sed -E 's/^([^0-9]*)0+/\1/'`?

Comment: What is `prefix`, `ID` and `suffix` in `ZZZ00004500AA010`?

Comment: Sorry guys, just figured it out my self :-)
 sed 's/ZZZ0*/ZZZ/'
Wil give me the result i was hoping for.
Thanx anyway

Comment: Where does the "string" come from. Did you save it in a variable, is it output from a command, or is it located in a file? This is information that is required to give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capture group to match the leading chars other than a digit, and then match 0 or more digits.

In the replacement use group 1.

```
^([^0-9]*)0+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NM4CRB/1)

```
echo "ZZZ00004500AA010" | sed -E 's/^([^0-9]*)0+/\1/'
echo "ZZZ004500AA010" | sed -E 's/^([^0-9]*)0+/\1/'
```

Output

```
ZZZ4500AA010
ZZZ4500AA010
```

---

If there have to be leading chars A-Z:

```
^([A-Z]+)0+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bW6Muz/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you know there's always at least one zero, you don't need sed at all, you can use parameter expansion. You can use a regex match to check there is a zero after the initial non-digits:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
for v in ZZZ00004500AA010 ZZZ004500AA010 ZZZ04500AA010 ZZZ4500AA010 ; do
    if [[ $v =~ ^[^0-9]+0 ]] ; then
        v=${v/+(0)/}
    fi
    echo "$v"
done
```

Output:

```
ZZZ4500AA010
ZZZ4500AA010
ZZZ4500AA010
ZZZ4500AA010
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
$ echo "ZZZ00004500AA010" | perl -pe 's{^([A-Za-z]+)0+}{$1}'
ZZZ4500AA010
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

`s{PATTERN}{REPLACEMENT}` : Change `PATTERN` to `REPLACEMENT`.
`^` : Beginning of the string.
`([A-Za-z]+)` : Match any letter repeated 1 or more times. Capture into capture group 1 (`$1`).
`0+` : zero, repeated 1 or more times.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)